# Check IP address range

Tags: sql, ip

I try to make IP to country query.

Simplest way is make query like this:

```
select  Country
from    dbip
where   8 * power(255,3) +
        8 * power(255,2) + 
        8 * power(255,1) + 8
        between FromIPInt and  ToIPInt
```

It works for small Google's IP, but for greater IP:
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.

Which other way I can compute it?

Comment: maybe you need to use a big int

Comment: What do you mean? cast (  as bigint) or convert(bigint? No one of these work

Comment: Before answer check it: select 184 * power(255,3) +
168 * power(255,2) + 
47 * power(255,1) + 17, can you compute it?  By cast? No. By convert? No.

Comment: frist things first! FromIPInt and ToIPInt are int or bigint? also I dont see a variable here just a big calculation ` 8 * power(255,3) +
    8 * power(255,2) + 
    8 * power(255,1) + 8`

Comment: Ok, try it: declare @ip bigint = 184 * power(255,3) +
168 * power(255,2) + 
47 * power(255,1) + 17; if you wish.

Comment: Minus? You even can't answer

Comment: I don't follow what you're asking here. Your equation  equals 133,173,248, which fits in an integer, I'm assuming `FromIPInt ` and `ToIPInt` are also integers, given their names, so the error doesn't make sense, can you provide sample data that illustrated the problem?

Comment: For 8.8.8.8 it is 133173248, but what is for 184 * power(255,3) + 168 * power(255,2) + 47 * power(255,1) + 17? And how you will compute it? 8.8.8.8 is small and computes without problems.

Comment: So the `8`s are actually variables, not a static number.  That makes more sense but isn't clear in the question.  I'm not familiar with this method of using IP's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CAST is the solution, but you have do put it in the right place :

```
select  Country
from    dbip
where   cast(255 as bigint) * power(255,3)
        +  255 * power(255,2)
        +  255 * power(255,1)
        +  255
        between FromIPInt and  ToIPInt
```

The error ***Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int*** occurs if you CAST the whole calculation:

```
select cast(255 * power(255,3) as bigint)
```

But not if you cast your first number

```
select cast(255 as bigint) * power(255,3)
```

More details about that: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx

> Integer constants greater than 2,147,483,647 are converted to the decimal data type, not the bigint data type.
>
> SQL Server does not automatically promote other integer data types (tinyint, smallint, and int) to bigint.

Comment: Don't hesitate to accept the answer if you found it useful ;-)